# Variable text label for select dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

I have a function that, taking a JSON array of objects, where each object has an id and a text field label (variable for each select), it populates the options.

The function I am trying to write is:

```
function populateSelect(urlString, id, tag){
    $.getJSON(urlString, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(){
            $(id).append($("<option></option>").text(this.tag).val(this.id));
        });
    });
}
```

So `this.id` will always be true as every JSON obect will have an attribute where the key is 'id'.  Yet `this.tag` is what I want to be variable as this can change for each type of JSON object/select I am building.

For example, two valid JSON objects I could be working with are:

```
[{id:'1', name:'John Doe'}, {id:2, name:'Jane Doe'}]
```

and

```
[{id:1, model:'Toyota'}, {id:2, model:'Honda'}]
```

Each of these JSON objects would be used to populate the `<option>` fields for the respective `<select>` element.  Thus for the first JSON object if this was not a function to be used for many different Select elements, that line would read:

```
$.(id).append($("<option></option>").text(this.name).val(this.id));
```

and the second JSON object would have a line that read:

```
$.(id).append($("<option></option>").text(this.model).val(this.id));
```

Apologies if any of the jargon is incorrect, I'm coming up to speed with JQuery.

Comment: shouldn't it be '$(id)' (without the dot?). Furthermore, I don't really understand what the problem is, sorry.

Comment: I added test JSON data, which might explain why (I believe) it is not $(id).

Comment: afaik $.() doens't really do anything. Could you provide a jsFiddle/jsBin/plnkr ?

Comment: Sorry, code typo has been edited.  I was unable to copy/paste code.

Comment: still 2 typos left :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
//get all the properties of the object
    var keys = Object.keys(value);
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = value.id;
//use the second property as inner html
    option.innerHTML = value[keys[1]];

        $("#mySelect").append(option);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e55kW/1/
I updated the jsFiddle of @jmm

Comment: That works.  I'll mark yours correct as it was an external answer, but my latest response also works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Yoeri pointed out your typo with `$.()`

Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/e55kW/) what your trying to attempt?

I just created a string and appended it to the select element.

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    var option = "<option value="+value.id +">"+ value.name + "</option>";

    $("#mySelect").append(option);
```

});

Comment: That is kind of what I am trying to do.  Your code works for the first JSON object (where the data has a key of 'name', but it does not work for the second JSON object, where the data has a value of 'model'

Comment: use document.createElement to create DOM objects rather than string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Found out (prior to coming back and seeing Yoeri's also correct response) that this works:

```
function populateSelect(urlString, id, tag){
    $.getJSON(urlString, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(){
            $(id).append($("<option></option>").text(this[tag]).val(this.id));
        });
    });
}
```

The difference from the above is that I changed `this.tag` to `this[tag]`